# How to get text Prediction accuracy from the saved model"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, text-classification, tensorflow.js

New to tensorflow, html, and stuck badly in text classification.

i'am trying to detect positive and negative polarity of text. trained the model in browser on manually filtered text (sentences) for both neagative and postive classes and saved it in .JSON and .BIN File.

```
async function saveFile(){ const saveResults = await model.save('downloads://my-model-1');}
```

Loaded back the files by user input

```
async function loadFile(){ const jsonUpload = document.getElementById('json-upload'); const weightsUpload = document.getElementById('weights-upload'); 
const model = await tf.loadModel(tf.io.browserFiles([jsonUpload.files[0], weightsUpload.files[0]]));
model.compile({loss: "categoricalCrossentropy", optimizer: "adam", metrics:'accuracy'});
model.summary();
}
```

[summary of model loaded, trained and saved from small portion of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWLRM.png)

stuck in Re_creating model ( ERROR:  Uncaught TypeError: Sequential model cannot be built: model is empty. Add some layers first.)

What i need to do is LOAD MODEL, this model should predict the polarity of user input text as negative/positive, detection accuracy.

Any one can help please in bit detailed, As learning it but not able to get it via tutorials from https://www.tensorflow.org/js

Model

```
// Define a model
        model = tf.sequential();
        console.log(sequence_length);
        //Add layers to model
        model.add(tf.layers.embedding({
        inputDim: vocabulary_size,
        outputDim: embedding_dim,
        inputLength: sequence_length,
        trainable: true
        }));
        addCLayers();
        model.add(tf.layers.dropout ({rate:0.2}));
        model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1000, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'sigmoid'}));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'}));
```

Comment: You don't need to compile your model after loading it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I see two issues.

**Firstly**, you're using `loadModel`, which has been deprecated.  You'll want to switch to `loadLayersModel` soon.  This can also accept an IOHandler, just like you're currently using.

**The second thing** is you need to compile the model before saving.  I see you're loading and then trying to compile.  There should be no need to compile after loading.  You ***CAN*** however load a layerless model.

Assure your model is in good standing before you save it.  That seems to be where the problem is.